# Unable to get promise value with Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm experimenting with NodeJS and the twitter API. I need help with a promise. The function `requestFollowers` should return a promise and it does. When I run the file in the node cli it says processing and never logs the value. How do I get the value I expect from it or how do I resolve it?

Here is what I have so for.

```js
function requestFollowers(tweep) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    twitter.get('followers/list', {
      count: 200,
      skip_status: true,
      screen_name: tweep
    }, function(error, followers) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('followers list/ error >', error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(followers.users.map(thing => thing.screen_name));
      }
    });
  });
}

function onMention(error, tweets) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('mentions_timeline/ error >', error);
  } else {
    //console.log('mentions_timeline/ tweets >', tweets);
    let mentioned = tweets[0].entities.user_mentions
      .filter(thing => thing.screen_name !== user.screen_name)
      .map(thing => thing.screen_name);

    var list1 = requestFollowers(mentioned[0]),
      list2 = requestFollowers(tweets[0].user.screen_name);

    console.log('list1 >', list1.then(val => val).catch(error => error));
    console.log('list2 >', list2.then(val => val).catch(error => error));
  }
}

var config = require('./config'),
  Twitter = require('twitter'),
  twitter = new Twitter(config),
  user = {
    screen_name: 'screen_name'
  },
  /** @param {string} status */
  getStatus = status => ({
    status
  });


twitter.get('statuses/mentions_timeline', user, onMention);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line `console.log('list1 >', list1.then(val => val).catch(error => error));` to something like

```
list1.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

What you had is passing an unresolved promise chain to `log` and log doesn't resolve promises for arguments before printing them -- its synchronous.  Also your `then(val => val)` is redundant even if that would work somehow -- you don't need another function that just returns its input.